# fetch array data in blade view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have an array which I return to a blade view. My array declaration looks like this:

```
 $data = array(
     $topSell,
     $quantity
 );
```

With the contained data structured like this:

```
[
  [
   {
    "id": 4,
    "author_id": 3,
    "category_id": 3
   },
   {
    "id": 5,
    "author_id": 2,
    "category_id": 1
   },
  ],
  [
    100,
    200
  ]
]
```

I return this array to my blade with:

```
return view('report',['value' => $data]);
```

I want to fetch this array in blade so it will look like:

```
id  author_id  Quantity
4      3         100
5      2         200
```

Comment: And where is the problem? Show us your blade file.

Comment: I think it would be better if you put the quantity in the topSell object/s (merge basically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$topSell` and `$quantity` always have the same size, you can just use a `for` loop:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($value[0]); $i++)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $value[0][$i]->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value[0][$i]->author_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value[1][$i] }}</td>
  </tr>
@endfor
```

Alternatively, you can modify your data to integrate the quantity to your objects:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data[0]); $i++) {
    $data[0][$i]->quantity = $data[1][$i];
}
```

And then, returning only the first sub array in the view:

```
return view('report',['value' => $data[0]]);
```

You can use a `foreach` in blade:

```
@foreach ($value as $element)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $element->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $element->author_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $element->quantity }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

More loop statements are detailed in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops).

Comment: Thanks it works. But there is a little modification  in for loop  $i < count($value[0]) . Because object can not converted as integer do.